# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] rooms validation failed: image: Path `image` is required

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs, buffer, multer

I want to upload image in mongoose database along with other room information using **Buffer** and **Express.Multer.File** in nestjs. Image show in the **uploads** folder in the project directory but showing error that image is required and data is not uploading to the mongoose.

The Code of **room.cshema.ts** is:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import mongoose, { Document } from "mongoose";
import { Booking } from "src/book/schemas/booking.schema";
import { guest } from "src/guests/schemas/guests.schema";


@Schema({
    timestamps: true,
})
export class rooms extends Document{

    @Prop({required: true})
    roomNo: number

    @Prop({required: true})
    type: string

    @Prop({required: true})
    price: number

    @Prop({required: true})
    status: boolean

    @Prop({required: true})
    description: string

    @Prop({ required: true})
    image: Buffer;

    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'guests' })
    guest: guest;

    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'bookings' })
    booking: Booking;
}

export const RoomSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(rooms)
```

The Code of  **room.service.ts** is:

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { rooms } from './schemas/schema.room';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { RoomDto } from './dto/room.dto';

@Injectable()
export class RoomService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(rooms.name)
        private RoomModel: mongoose.Model<rooms>
    ){}

    async findAll(): Promise<rooms[]>{
        const rooms = await this.RoomModel.find();
        return rooms;
    }

    async create(  room: rooms, images: Express.Multer.File): Promise<rooms>{
        if(!images){
            throw new UnauthorizedException("image not found")
        }
        
        room.image = images.buffer;
        const res = await this.RoomModel.create(room);
        return res;
    }

}
```

The Code of **room.controller.ts** is:

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Param, Post, Req, UploadedFile, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RoomService } from './room.service';
import { rooms } from './schemas/schema.room';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';

@Controller('room')
export class RoomController {
    constructor(
        private roomService: RoomService
    ){}



@Get()
async getAllrooms(): Promise<rooms[]>{
    return this.roomService.findAll()

    }

@Post()
@UseInterceptors(
  FileInterceptor('image', {
      storage: diskStorage({
          destination: './uploads',
          filename: (req, file, cb) => {
              const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
              cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix);
          },
      }),
  }),
)
async createrooms(
    @Body()
    room,
    @UploadedFile() images: Express.Multer.File,
    ): Promise<rooms>{
        return this.roomService.create( room, images );
    }

}
```

And here is the screenshot of **postman** page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWTzP.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As is mentioned in Multer's documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), the `.buffer` property only exists when you save the file to memory. As you are using the `DiskStorage`, there is no `.buffer` and so when you create your `Room` object in mongoose, there's a validation error because you are passing `undefined`.

If you are already saving the file to disk, you should save the file *path* to your database, so that you can retrieve the file's binary data at a later point without slowing down the database in its retreival

Comment: thanks, for your answer. can you please update the code for me.